# PowerShell - Match characters AFTER pattern

Tags: powershell

I have the following String, not separated by lines (it is the output of a Posh-SSh connection):

```
                               Active : Cumulative : Peak Concur : Inactive
                             ----------------------------------------------
AnyConnect Client            :    959 :       1652 :        1028 :       31
  SSL/TLS/DTLS               :    959 :       1652 :        1028 :       31
Site-to-Site VPN             :      5 :         35 :           5
  IKEv2 IPsec                :      2 :         24 :           2
  IKEv1 IPsec                :      3 :         11 :           3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total Active and Inactive    :    995             Total Cumulative :   1687
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tunnels Summary
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                               Active : Cumulative : Peak Concurrent   
                             ----------------------------------------------
IKEv1                        :      3 :         11 :               3
IKEv2                        :      2 :         24 :               2
IPsec                        :      7 :         45 :               9
AnyConnect-Parent            :    990 :       1652 :            1028
SSL-Tunnel                   :    912 :       2698 :             962
DTLS-Tunnel                  :    857 :       2813 :             889
```

What I want to extract is "**AnyConnect Client            :    959 :** ", indeed, "**959**" is the string I need.

With this expression on Select-String I get the match, but I just need the chars after the pattern, let's say 50 characters (and after that I will extract the numbers):

```
Select-String -Pattern "(?=.*AnyConnect Client).*"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a look-behind (`(?<=PATTERN)`) instead of a look-ahead (`(?=PATTERN)`):

```bsh
$String |Select-String -Pattern "(?<=.*AnyConnect Client\D*)\d+" |ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Value}
```